# USB mouse late to load

Tags: 10.10, usb, 64-bit

I was using 10.04 going into this weekend and, after a kernel update, I began to observe some unreliable USB behaviour: namely, my USB mouse is extremely late to the party (usually turns on several seconds after login) and my USB card reader pretty much isn't working at all.

In the hopes of the latest and greatest taking care of it, and being in need of the switch to x64, I upgraded to 10.10 and was disappointed to find that the problems are still here.

I'm not terribly familiar with Ubuntu's USB systems these days so I'm asking the question: how do I begin to diagnose this issue?

Update 1:
I've added noapictimer and irqpoll to my kernel command.  No change.

Update 2:
I've unplugged all usb devices save for the mouse and the internal multi-card reader (connected to one of the mainboard's USB headers).  The dmesg output below is the result.

Some relevant dmesg output: you can see how long it's taking to bring the mouse online.

```
$ dmesg | egrep "hci|usb"
[    0.711064] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.711064] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.711064] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.055260] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.055298] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    1.055318] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.055355] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.055382] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: debug port 1
[    1.055407] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: irq 17, io mem 0xfe02c000
[    1.060140] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.060335] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    1.060347] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.060373] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.060399] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2: debug port 1
[    1.060423] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2: irq 19, io mem 0xfe029000
[    1.080132] ehci_hcd 0000:00:13.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.080269] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.080317] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    1.080330] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.080351] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.080379] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02e000
[    1.144302] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    1.144313] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.144333] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.144348] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02d000
[    1.204319] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    1.204331] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.204353] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    1.204381] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02b000
[    1.264325] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    1.264336] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.264358] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    1.264373] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02a000
[    1.324323] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    1.324335] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.324361] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    1.324376] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: irq 18, io mem 0xfe028000
[    1.384279] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.435428] firewire_ohci 0000:03:0e.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[    1.436716] ahci 0000:00:11.0: version 3.0
[    1.436730] ahci 0000:00:11.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[    1.436827] ahci 0000:00:11.0: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 4 ports 3 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    1.436829] ahci 0000:00:11.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo pmp pio slum part ccc 
[    1.438473] scsi2 : ahci
[    1.438554] scsi3 : ahci
[    1.438601] scsi4 : ahci
[    1.438638] scsi5 : ahci
[    1.440179] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
[    1.490160] firewire_ohci: Added fw-ohci device 0000:03:0e.0, OHCI v1.10, 4 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x2
[   16.560107] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   31.790134] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   32.020129] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[   47.150111] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   62.380130] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   62.610125] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[   73.030125] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 4, error -110
[       73.150122] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[   83.570186] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 5, error -110
[   83.760195] usb 4-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 2
[   83.992508] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
[   83.997139] input: Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input3
[   83.997357] generic-usb 0003:045E:0040.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)] on usb-0000:00:12.1-2/input0
[   83.997402] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   83.997408] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   84.260207] usb 6-3: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 2
[   99.410194] usb 6-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  114.670184] usb 6-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  114.950222] usb 6-3: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 3
[  130.100199] usb 6-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  145.360206] usb 6-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  145.620188] usb 6-3: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 4
[  156.040197] usb 6-3: device not accepting address 4, error -110
[  156.210204] usb 6-3: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 5
[  166.630203] usb 6-3: device not accepting address 5, error -110
```

And for the record.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The card reader is missing completely from the output above, unfortunately.  It was working about 2 weeks ago, until a kernel update when I was running 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
The dmesg show a lot of read error regarding USB devices, they may be the cause
of the mouse bad performance.
The user experienced that disconnecting the other USB devices made his mouse work again.

---

It could be an APIC problem, as a workaround you can try to boot your system with the options:

```
noapictimer irqpoll
```

To do that you need to modify the /etc/default/grub file. Step:

- Backup the file `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak`
- Open the file in gedit `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub` and enter your password
- Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Replace that line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noapictimer irqpoll"`
- Save the file and update your grub configuration `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot your system

If you want to rollback the changes just restore the grub.bak file and sudo update-grub again :)

Comment: Very complete answer: thank you.   I'll give these a go when I return home and see if it works.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Mh.. from your dmesg I can see a lot of USB error/retry. Can you disconnect any USB devices except your mouse and reboot?

Comment: After finally opening up the case, removing my internal card reader, and rebooting, the mouse came back.

I powered down, switched the card reader to another mainboard USB header and rebooted again and the card reader came back as well.

Not what I would've expected.  Post your last comment as an answer and I'll accept it as an answer to the question.

Comment: done :) Glad that my comment helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a default Maverick install or have you made any changes?  e.g adding the facial recognition piece to GDM.

I will admit I have the same issue, but I reboot so infrequently I rareley notice the problem.  It only seems to occur on my desktop and not my laptop.

Comment: This is a default Maverick install.